# php isset() is not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

At first I posted my code:

```
//if ($filterResults['id']) {
  if (isset($filterResults['id'])){
            $select = $this->select();
            $select->where('id = ?', $filterResults['id']);

        $this->fetchAll($select);


        }
```

Now, the problem is if I use `if ($filterResults['id']) {` it gives the expected result but if I use `if (isset($filterResults['id'])){` it doesn't work. I don't see any reason behind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I use the isset() like this:

```
if ( isset($filterResults['id']) && $filterResults['id'] != null ){
        $select = $this->select();
        $select->where('id = ?', $filterResults['id']);

    $this->fetchAll($select);


    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`isset()` will return false if the value is NULL. If this is a possibility you may wish to use `array_key_exists()` instead:

```
if (array_key_exists('id', $filterResults)) {
    [...]
}
```